# How to prevent multiple meterpreter sessions from same target?

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I use a custom `android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` payload from [here](https://github.com/giovannicolonna/msfvenom-backdoor-android). It connects back to the handler at specified time interval. When I use exploit as a job, I get multiple sessions from the same target using different ports.

I want the handler to refuse the session from a target if a session from that target already exits in the jobs. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What command did you use to make the handler repeat the connection attempt?

Comment: @J.A.K. just the standard /multi/handler with exploit run with modifier '-j'

Comment: Typo, I meant the payload. (standard meterpreter doesn't repeatedly connect back unless persistance is run)

Comment: @J.A.K. am using a custom android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp payload. https://github.com/giovannicolonna/msfvenom-backdoor-android. And my primary question doesn't concern the payload. I just want to know if the listener can refuse a session from a target, if the target already has a successful session. ty

Comment: IDK, maybe you can try to use iptables for that.